# Error deploy BMP project using Tibco Business Studio

Tags: tibco, business-process-management

I try to deploy a BPM project but I get error when create application as such:

> create.app:[AMXAdminTask]  INFO - Processing 1 objects[AMXAdminTask] 
>   INFO - Adding application...[AMXAdminTask] ERROR - Failed to add
>   Application 'com.example.bmpsample'[AMXAdminTask] ERROR - Follower
>   application component
>   urn:amx:BPMEnvironment/com.example.bmpsample/BMPSampleProcessFlow_1.0.0.201311211151
>   requires capability
>   com.tibco.amf.sca.model.componenttype.impl.RequiredCapabilityImpl@7396acb
>   (id: com.tibco.bx.capability.implementation.bx, version: 1.0.0, type:
>   factory) but the target application does not provide it.
>
> BUILD
>   FAILEDD:\wsbmp.BSServers\scripts\com.example.bmpsample.deployment-build.xml:37:
>   Failed on error Total time: 7 seconds

Comment: Which version of AMX BPM are you using?

Comment: Version's AXM BPM is 2.1

Comment: If i don't add Tester participant into process, the build project will without error. So, I had build and deloy new empty project to bpm server successful.

Answer (score 0):

I also got same error while deploying bpm project from studio, to resolve that below information will help you :

**Summary** When using TIBCO Business Studio to deploy a DAA that is 
dependant on another DAA which is not in the deployed state results in errors 
such as:

Follower application component 
urn:amx:BPMEnvironment/com.example.appa/APPAProcessFlow requires 
capability

com.tibco.amf.sca.model.componenttype.impl.RequiredCapabilityImp
l@7ee0f191 (id: com.tibco.bx.capability.implementation.bx, 
version: 1.0.0, type: factory) but the target application does 
not provide it.

**Workaround** Make sure the dependant DAA is deployed.

Thanks & Regards,
Srinivasa Reddy P